# Semantic Meaning of a tuple not equal to zero

Tags: scala, tuples

```
val tuple = (1,2)  //> tuple  : (Int, Int) = (1,2)
tuple !=0          //> res0: Boolean = true

val tuple1 = (0,0) //> tuple1  : (Int, Int) = (0,0)
tuple1 !=0         //> res1: Boolean = true
```

I thought the above should not compile.. but it does. If so, what does this mean? In what context, does comparing a tuple to zero make sense?
Also, As you can see tuple which is non-zero gives true when compared to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare any object with any other. If they are of different types (as a tuple and the integer zero will always be), they will always be unequal. You can use scalaz' `=/=` and `===` if you want to require that the compared objects are the same type at compile time.

Comment: but why does object comparison return true? should it not return false as they are completely different objects?

Comment: `==` in Scala is simply calling `obj1.equals(obj2)`, so it follows the semantics of the `equals` method which allows the objects to be different types, just returning false.